# Irreducible representation with trace zero in positive characteristic

Tags: representation-theory

Is there an example of an ***irreducible*** representation $\rho:G\rightarrow GL_n(F)$ where $char(F)>0$ such that $trace(\rho(g))=0$ for all $g\in G$?

Of course we have to consider $F$ and $G$ (finite group) with $F[G]$ *non-semi-simple*.

Comment: I almost thought that $D_4$ over $F_2$ would be an example, since the standard two-dimensional representation is indecomposible over $F_2$, but it does not remain irreducible over $F_2$.

Comment: @Kyle Right, no $p$-group can provide an example since all their irreducibles are $1$-dimensional in chap $p$.

Comment: This question has been previously asked and answered on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252855/can-an-irreducible-representation-have-a-zero-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this has an answer (I'll make the post community wiki since it's not my answer):

This answer on MathOverflow says that I.M. Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups, Corollary 9.22, Dover, p. 155, states that every irreducible representation of a finite group over any field has a non-zero character.